# Index finger picking problem on an acoustic guitar

Tags: fingerstyle-guitar

I have been practicing guitar for around 2.5 years now and I have been bugged with a certain problem for a long time. Occasionally when I pick a string using ONLY my index finger, the guitar emits a very bad sound, as if the strings are being swiped. It feels like my finger was just sliding on the string(as opposed to actually picking). Interestingly, this only happens with my index finger, picking done by my other fingers sounds just fine. Is this a problem with my nails? My strings? Or just bad technique? If it is indeed just bad technique, can I get a few tips/pointers? Thank you.

Comment: 90% it is a matter of technique, something minor but sufficient to produce the undesired effect. If you can, have a good player look at your technique. Alternatively, post a video (as close up and as sharp as possible) and you'll most likely get several useful tips.

Comment: As i thought. Currently I use the part near my inner nails to pick. Is that wrong? Also, does nail length matter? I have small fingers, so even a bit of nail could interfere with my playing

Comment: You should definitely grow out your nails, it makes a world of difference. Also make sure to file and shape your nails.